# Query with simplifying arbitrary constants

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, constants

[image]

I'm confused with this procedure above. Why is this justified? Because $x(t) = e^{3t+c_1} + 1$ is the same thing as $x(t) = e^{3t}e^{c_1} +1$. Are they assuming that $e^{c_1}$ is just some constant scaling $e^{3t}$? If so, then shouldn't it be some new constant $c_2$? What sense is it making it the same as $c_1$? Because would that not imply that $e^{c_1} = c_1$ according to this answer?

Comment: It would help if you added some context, for example: what function does $x(t)$ represent? If $x(t)$ was some power of $e$ it could make more sense.

Comment: As you say, this isn't really justified. This should be a new arbitrary constant. But this is an "abuse of notation" that occurs frequently in this subject.

Comment: It is $x^{a+b}=x^a\cdot x^b$. And you are right the new variable should have a new name.

Comment: you could "reuse" the name $c_1$ after you discard the old meaning. So, then "new" $c_1$ is the $exp($ old $c_1)$. Since old $c_1$ wasn't much needed, the authors didn't feel it must be preserved.

Comment: Just rename $e^{c_1}=c_2$ and later, rename $c_2$ as $c_1$. Since they are constants,....